# Duplicate popups in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, user-interface, data-explorer, popups

Every time you click the "*n sql*" links in the data explorer, it pops up a new dialog, even if one is already showing. This isn't immediately obvious, but you can see it by looking at the backdrop color.

[image: 0 popups]
[image: 1 popup]
[image: 2 popups]
[image: 3 popups]

If you click on the backdrop, all of the popups disappear.

I know this is a minor issue, and I didn't even know about this feature until I started playing around with it a few hours ago, but I thought I'd bring it up anyway.

Comment: This is presumably a MiniProfiler bug, so upgrading to the latest might fix things in SEDE...if not I'll fix it on that end.